# What's wrong with my javascript function in selecting a default value in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

My job is to default a value in a dropdown select. I was able to do that, my problem is, it seems that the value defaulted by my function seems null? By the way, I did not use the attribute (selected="selected") since the options are dynamically created. I just put a option value in my example to better understand.

HTML:

```
    <tr>
      <td>Status Found</td>
      <td>
        <select id="lstExtStatusFound">
           <option value=" "> </option>
           <option value="ON">On</option>
           <option value="OFF">Off</option>
        </select>    
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>Status Left</td>
      <td>
        <select id="lstExtStatusLeft">
           <option value=" "> </option>
           <option value="ON">On</option>
           <option value="OFF">Off</option>
        </select>    
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function defaultStatus(){ 
        var statusFound = document.getElementById("lstExtStatusFound").selectedIndex = 2;
        statusFound.selected = true;

        var statusLeft = document.getElementById("lstExtStatusLeft").selectedIndex = 2;
        statusLeft.selected = true;

    }
```

Comment: looks fine it is working

Comment: Your code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not your main problem but when you assign `document.getElementById("lstExtStatusFound").selectedIndex = 2` to variable, this variable will have value `2`.

To store dom element you should create variable just for this and then operate on its properties

```
var statusFound = document.getElementById("lstExtStatusFound")
statusFound.selectedIndex = 2;
statusFound.selected = true;
```

And also for me it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/p3pbguus/1/